# Uploading a file with multer does not let request to be handled

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman, multer

I'm trying to create a rest api that would accept some simple data for an item. I used to use multer as file handler in my project. Here is my code for importing and handling the multer config:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

And here is the corresponding `app.post` route for that:

```
// POST
router.post('/', upload.single('pi') ,(req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  // console.log(req.file);
  console.log('hi there')
  const product = new Product({
    // _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    nm:   req.body.name,
    pr:   req.body.price,
    ca:   req.body.category,
    ti:   req.body.title,
    tg:   req.body.tag
  })

  product
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Handeling POST requests...',
        createdProduct: {
          _id: result._id,
          nm:  result.nm,
          pr:  result.pr,
          ca:  result.ca,
          ti:  result.ti,
          tg:  result.tg,
          meta: {
            type: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:4000/products/' + result._id,
          }
        }
      })
      // console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      })
    })
})
```

## The Problem

The problem is that file is being uploaded to the `uploads/` directory but the product is not being created. After the file is being uploaded to the corresponding directory I'm getting `Could not get any response` in Postman. Also I tried to log the `req.body` inside the multer but I did not get any thing in my terminal. I also set my `Content-Type:` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I'm using `form-data` in postman.

Comment: Are you getting inside the route or the console displaying hi there ?

Comment: it seems that file is been uploading and the path for the file is been created in mongo, but post man is responding me like that , what could be the problem ???

Comment: Cant say anything the code you wrote is looking fine might be you are doing any mistake while debugging in postman

Comment: The code you have written is completely fine. Something is happening in saving the record. Comment out the mongo code and try again.